# iOS - NSDate contain wrong hour value

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm running iOS 10.0.2 and upgraded it to iOS 10.1.1 with the same problem, whenever trying to use `NSDate` it has a wrong hour value, for example:

```
let now = NSDate()
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
timeLabel.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(now)
```

It will display in `timeLabel` as `1212:15` and the current time is `12:15`, is it an iOS bug or do I have something wrong with my device, it's an iPhone 6s.

I've printed the `now` variable to console, it has this value `2016-11-23 99:31:16 AM +0000`, it should be like this `2016-11-23 09:31:16 AM +0000`

So, the pattern of `NSDate()` is like this:

```
2016-11-23 1414:31:16 AM +0000
2016-11-23 2222:31:16 AM +0000
2016-11-23 2020:31:16 AM +0000
2016-11-23 1212:31:16 AM +0000
```

Comment: I tried this in playground. It worked fine. I think there is nothing wrong with your code

Comment: @KrishnaCA, Yes, on other device, the code working fine, just on the mentioned device it's not working and give these weird values.

Comment: Did you try rebooting your device? May be changing timezone in settings

Comment: May be the issue is with your `NSTimeZone.local()`

Comment: @Rajat @Rob if I use the following code, the time become correct to display `if(use24HourFormat) {
            dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_GB");
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm";
        } else {
            dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX");
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a";
        }`

Comment: But still, all the logic of my app is based on NSDate object, not a formatter, like differences between 2 dates, for example, so this did not help me so much

Comment: Often, if you want it in a 24-hour clock, you do `dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")`. Then your `dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"` should work fine.

Comment: @Rob, Yes, but still the `NSDate` object that hold the date is totally wrong as mentioned above, I've printed `NSLocale.currentLocale().localeIdentifier` and this is what it gave me: `"he_IL"`

Comment: I'm very confused by your output, though, if you're outputting the "HH:mm", how in the world are you seeing year, month, day, etc., too.? I set my formatter's locale to `"he_IL"`, and don't see anything strange. It's hard to help you when we can't reproduce the behavior you describe...

Comment: It looks like there are two things going on here — `2016-11-23 1414:31:16 AM +0000` looks like the pattern produced when printing a `Date`, say, in the debugger. The date formatter itself is a separate concern. (Both related problems though.)

Comment: @Scar What is the result that you see for `NSTimeZone.localTimeZone().name`? `localTimeZone`, by the way, is not necessarily the same thing as the _user's_ time zone, which is tracked by `NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()`, or `TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent`....

Comment: @ItaiFerber I found out recently that this issue is gone by using `dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")`, I've did not figure out why, but it solve the issue for date formatter.